# Elementary subsctructure of $L_{\omega_1}$

Tags: set-theory

Let us consider $A$ the family of all elements of $L_{\omega_1}$ definable without parameters. I was trying to prove that assuming $V=L$ then $A$ is an elementary substructure of $L_{\omega_1}$ by means of the Tarski-Vaught criterion. My problem is that I do not know how to ensure the existence of a $b\in A$ such that $\psi[a,b]^{L_{\omega_1}}$ provided that if $\phi(x)=\exists y\,\psi(x,y)$ then $a\in A$ is such that $\phi[a]^{L_{\omega_1}}$.

Every comment or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: there is a definable-in-$L$-without-parameters well-ordering of $L$. Do you see how to use this to get a canonical (hence in $A$) witness $b$ to $\psi[a, -]^{L_{\omega_1}}$?